# Tweet share button does not render on login/logout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, meteor

I am using Meteor's `accounts-ui` package with `accounts-twitter` on an app which consists of thumbnails with content from database. Each thumbnail also has a tweet share button. I am facing a peculiar issue where the tweet button does not render when a user logs in or logs out of the app.

On page load, the tweet button renders well but when the user clicks either login or logout, either the element disappears or the styling goes away and is left with only text.

There is no event handling code on login or logout. I've added the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/kvprashant/5117204).

Does it have something to do with the page not refreshing? Has this behaviour been noticed before?

Comment: Simply wrap the elements like so: `{{#constant}}<hr>{{/constant}}`. Meteor has [constant regions](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant) and doing this stops the element from re-rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @zorlak's answer this is what I did:

**HTML**:

```
<template name="listings">
  {{twitter "@MeteorAtSO"}}
</template>


<template name="twitter">
  <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
     src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1362636220.html#_=1363023601135&amp;
       count=none&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;
       lang=en&amp;original_referer=http://localhost:3000&amp;
       text=Check out {{this}}!&amp;
       url=http://localhost:3000"&amp;size=m 
     class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-none" 
     style="width: 58px; height: 20px;" 
     title="Twitter Tweet Button" 
     data-twttr-rendered="true">
  </iframe>
</template>
```

**Javascript**:

```
Template.twitter.rendered = function() {
  return !function(d,s,id) {
           var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if(!d.getElementById(id)){
             js=d.createElement(s);
             js.id=id;
             js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
           }
   }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
}
```

And it worked out perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3):

The js code that twitter loads turns tweet buttons into iframes.  I've gotten around this by looking at the generated iframe in the inspector and then changing my code so instead of the anchor tag with data attributes, there's an iframe tag with the URL that I found in the inspector.  There's a pattern to it too, so you should be able to make a template that renders different buttons with different urls.

I think the problem with doing it the way you're doing it now (which was the way I did it at first too) is that the twitter code that converts tweet buttons into iframes only runs once, even if you load the script multiple times.  So if you create a tweet tag after the twitter code has already run, it won't get converted to an iframe and won't work or look like a tweet button.

Comment: Liked you said I inspected the iframe element and copied the HTML and used the pattern to load different text and URLs. Thanks!

Comment: In case you're still using the iframe, you can now wrap the twitter template around [constant regions](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant). This simply stops it from re-rendering.

Comment: @Prashant glad I could help!  I don't use a {{#constant}} region for this because Meteor's event handlers and helpers don't work inside constant regions.

Comment: Well, in case of the Tweet Share button, there is nothing being handled on Meteor's side. But in other cases, as you mentioned, `{{#constant}}` doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing to use `rendered`

```
Template.twitter.rendered = function() {
  return !function(d,s,id) {
           var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if(!d.getElementById(id)){
             js=d.createElement(s);
             js.id=id;
             js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
           }
   }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
}
```

Don't worry about the re-render adding twitter's api script in multiple times there's a check in there to allow it to run multiple times & only act if its js removed.

I suspect the re-render (while logging out/changing a reactive variable) is destroying the links to the css created by the js for twitter's api for that share button.

Comment: Doesn't work either. However, `console.log("rendered")` works in `Template.twitter.rendered` both in login and logout.

Comment: Could you use chrome/webkit inspector to check the css that twitter adds before and after you login and in which template/where in your html its placing it in & if it gets removed

Comment: I looked into the chrome inspector and see that the HTML is the original used in the template. This means that the javascript is not being executed on template render. Also, the app has been registered for localhost. Not sure if that's affecting this behaviour.

Comment: I just found out. Meteor has something called [constant regions](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant) and elements wrapped around `{{#constant}}<hr>{{/constant}}` do not re-render

Comment: You could do this but don't you have reactive variables in there? They wont be parsed out

Comment: What about using `{{#constant}}` and then using jquery and meteor.autorun (to make it reactive) to change the html which would contain your reactive variable?

Comment: Using Twitter Share button within `{{#constant}}`. In my use case it is one-time load and data does not change later. Should try your suggestion in case of reactive variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on the solution here, you can use the below to further customize your shareable button

```
Template.listings.twitterDetails = function() {
    return {
        text: "What do you want to say?"
        , url: "what link do you want to share?"
        , referer: "yoursite.com"
        , id: Random.id()
    };
};
```

And

```
{{#with twitterDetails}}
    {{>twitter}}
{{/with}}
```

And

```
<template name="twitter">
  <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
    src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.{{id}}.html#_={{id}}&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer={{referer}}&text={{text}}&url={{url}}&size=l"
     class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-none" 
     style="width: 77px; height: 28px;" 
     title="Twitter Tweet Button" 
     data-twttr-rendered="true">
  </iframe>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to display twitter button without 'iframe', here is how: [../twitter-buttons-in-meteor.html](http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.cz/2013/06/twitter-buttons-in-meteor.html)